# Show pictures with details and hide

Tags: jquery, css

I need help to implement an idea I had only for learning purposes.

I would like to click on an image, open it with 100% wide and the right I would open a description of the image and hide the others who were inside the div "content".

Of course, after I click on the image again I would return to the previous laytout.

I'm trying, but I'm really stuck on how to implement.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".frame").on("click", function() {

    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this, ".information").css('display', "inline");

    if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
      $(this).css('width', "100%");

    } else {

      $(".frame").css("visibility", "hidden");

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.frame {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.information {
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.image {
  border: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.sowhowins.com/Character%20Pictures/He-Man2.png" alt="Test" />
      <div class="information">
        This is He-man
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://images.amazon.com/images/G/01/dvd/aplus/transformers/transformers8-hi.jpg" alt="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="information">
      This is He-man
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/36900000/Bumblebee-the-transformers-36906761-1000-1286.jpg" alt="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="information">
      This is He-man
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://media.popcultcha.com.au/media/catalog/product/s/i/sid26121.png" alt="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="information">
      This is He-man
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/1000041-product-silo.png" alt="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="information">
      This is He-man
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A mockup of what you want would go a long way here.  Your code snippet makes it clear what you *have* currently; but a mockup with a little time in a graphics program would make it clear(er) what you *want*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By tweaking the following in CSS

```
.frame.expanded{
    width:100%;
}
.information {
  float: right;
  display:none;
}
.frame.expanded .information{
    display:block;
}
```

You can clean up your code a little bit, and then just .hide() everything and specifically show the clicked .frame

```
$(function() {
  $(".frame").on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")){
          $(".frame").show();
          $(this).removeClass("expanded");
      } else {
          $(".frame").hide();
          $(this).show()
          $(this).addClass("expanded");
      }
  });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/9w0qe47g/1/

Comment: Yes. You made it. What do you think if I by an animation to hide other divs? It would be less static.

Comment: if you just put a 500 in each of your show/hide, it'll give you a simple animation.  If you have more content on the page, you might want to specify a hight for #content

Answer (score 0):

You better use `.hover()` function. That will be easy.

```
$(function() {

  $(".frame").hover( function() {
      $(".frame").hide();
      $(this).show();
      $(this).addClass("expanded");
  },function(){
      $(".frame").show();
      $(this).removeClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hemnathmouli/oxzqyxot/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think would be better the click. Don't you think?